# What's the proper way to handle back-pressure in a node.js Transform stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

### Intro

These are my first adventures in writing the node.js server side. It's been
fun so far but I'm having some difficulty understanding the proper way
to implement something as it relates to node.js streams.

#### Problem

For test and learning purposes I'm working with large files whose
content is zlib compressed. The compressed content is binary data, each
*packet* being 38 bytes in length. I'm trying to create a resulting file
that looks almost identical to the original file except that there is an
uncompressed 31-byte header for every 1024 38-byte *packets*.

#### Original file content (decompressed)

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| packet 1 | packet 2 |  ......  | packet N |
| 38 bytes | 38 bytes |  ......  | 38 bytes |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

#### Resulting file content

```
+----------+--------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+
| header 1 |    1024 38 byte packets        | header 2 |    1024 38 byte packets        |
| 31 bytes |       zlib compressed          | 31 bytes |       zlib compressed          |
+----------+--------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

As you can see, it's somewhat of a translation problem. This means, I'm
taking some source stream as input and then slightly transforming it
into some output stream. Therefore, it felt natural to implement a
[Transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform).

The class simply attempts to accomplish the following:

1. Takes stream as input
2. zlib inflates the chunks of data to count the number of packets,
   putting together 1024 of them, zlib deflating, and
   prepending a header.
3. Passes the new resulting chunk on through the pipeline via
   `this.push(chunk)`.

A use case would be something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var me = require('./me'); // Where my Transform stream code sits
var inp = fs.createReadStream('depth_1000000');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('depth_1000000.out');
inp.pipe(me.createMyTranslate()).pipe(out);
```

#### Question(s)

Assuming **Transform** is a good choice for this use case, I seem to be
running into a possible back-pressure issue. My call to `this.push(chunk)`
within `_transform` keeps returning `false`. Why would this be and how
to handle such things?

Comment: The explanation on the transform file about back pressure is pretty good https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_transform.js, I found exactly what I was looking for there

Answer (score 15):

This question from 2013 is all I was able to find on how to deal with "back pressure"
when creating node Transform streams.

From the node 7.10.0 [Transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) and [Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) documentation what I gathered
was that once `push` returned false, nothing else should be pushed until `_read` was
called.

The Transform documentation doesn't mention `_read` except to mention that the base Transform
class implements it (and _write). I found the information about `push` returning false
and `_read` being called in the [Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) documentation.

The only other authoritative comment I found on Transform back pressure only mentioned
it as an issue, and that was in a comment at the top of the node file [_stream_transform.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_transform.js).

Here's the section about back pressure from that comment:

```
// This way, back-pressure is actually determined by the reading side,
// since _read has to be called to start processing a new chunk.  However,
// a pathological inflate type of transform can cause excessive buffering
// here.  For example, imagine a stream where every byte of input is
// interpreted as an integer from 0-255, and then results in that many
// bytes of output.  Writing the 4 bytes {ff,ff,ff,ff} would result in
// 1kb of data being output.  In this case, you could write a very small
// amount of input, and end up with a very large amount of output.  In
// such a pathological inflating mechanism, there'd be no way to tell
// the system to stop doing the transform.  A single 4MB write could
// cause the system to run out of memory.
//
// However, even in such a pathological case, only a single written chunk
// would be consumed, and then the rest would wait (un-transformed) until
// the results of the previous transformed chunk were consumed.
```

### Solution example

Here's the solution I pieced together to handle the back pressure in a Transform stream
which I'm pretty sure works. (I haven't written any real tests, which would require
writing a Writable stream to control the back pressure.)

This is a rudimentary Line transform which needs work as a line transform but does
demonstrate handling the "back pressure".

```
const stream = require('stream');

class LineTransform extends stream.Transform
{
    constructor(options)
    {
        super(options);

        this._lastLine = "";
        this._continueTransform = null;
        this._transforming = false;
        this._debugTransformCallCount = 0;
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback)
    {
        if (encoding === "buffer")
            return callback(new Error("Buffer chunks not supported"));

        if (this._continueTransform !== null)
            return callback(new Error("_transform called before previous transform has completed."));

        // DEBUG: Uncomment for debugging help to see what's going on
        //console.error(`${++this._debugTransformCallCount} _transform called:`);

        // Guard (so we don't call _continueTransform from _read while it is being
        // invoked from _transform)
        this._transforming = true;

        // Do our transforming (in this case splitting the big chunk into lines)
        let lines = (this._lastLine + chunk).split(/\r\n|\n/);
        this._lastLine = lines.pop();

        // In order to respond to "back pressure" create a function
        // that will push all of the lines stopping when push returns false,
        // and then resume where it left off when called again, only calling
        // the "callback" once all lines from this transform have been pushed.
        // Resuming (until done) will be done by _read().
        let nextLine = 0;
        this._continueTransform = () =>
            {
                let backpressure = false;
                while (nextLine < lines.length)
                {

                    if (!this.push(lines[nextLine++] + "\n"))
                    {
                        // we've got more to push, but we got backpressure so it has to wait.
                        if (backpressure)
                            return;

                        backpressure = !this.push(lines[nextLine++] + "\n");
                    }
                }

                // DEBUG: Uncomment for debugging help to see what's going on
                //console.error(`_continueTransform ${this._debugTransformCallCount} finished\n`);

                // All lines are pushed, remove this function from the LineTransform instance
                this._continueTransform = null;
                return callback();
            };

        // Start pushing the lines
        this._continueTransform();

        // Turn off guard allowing _read to continue the transform pushes if needed.
        this._transforming = false;
    }

    _flush(callback)
    {
        if (this._lastLine.length > 0)
        {
            this.push(this._lastLine);
            this._lastLine = "";
        }

        return callback();
    }

    _read(size)
    {
        // DEBUG: Uncomment for debugging help to see what's going on
        //if (this._transforming)
        //    console.error(`_read called during _transform ${this._debugTransformCallCount}`);

        // If a transform has not pushed every line yet, continue that transform
        // otherwise just let the base class implementation do its thing.
        if (!this._transforming && this._continueTransform !== null)
            this._continueTransform();
        else
            super._read(size);
    }
}
```

I tested the above by running it with the DEBUG lines uncommented on a ~10000 line
~200KB file. Redirect stdout or stderr to a file (or both) to separate the debugging
statements from the expected output. (`node test.js > out.log 2> err.log`)

```
const fs = require('fs');
let inStrm = fs.createReadStream("testdata/largefile.txt", { encoding: "utf8" });
let lineStrm = new LineTransform({ encoding: "utf8", decodeStrings: false });
inStrm.pipe(lineStrm).pipe(process.stdout);
```

### Helpful debugging hint

While writing this initially I didn't realize that `_read` could be called **before**
`_transform` returned, so I hadn't implemented the `this._transforming` guard and I was
getting the following error:

```
Error: no writecb in Transform class
    at afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:71:33)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:54:12)
    at LineTransform._continueTransform (/userdata/mjl/Projects/personal/srt-shift/dist/textfilelines.js:44:13)
    at LineTransform._transform (/userdata/mjl/Projects/personal/srt-shift/dist/textfilelines.js:46:21)
    at LineTransform.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at LineTransform._read (/userdata/mjl/Projects/personal/srt-shift/dist/textfilelines.js:56:15)
    at LineTransform.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:331:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:317:5)
    at LineTransform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:243:11)
```

Looking at the node implementation I realized that this error meant that the callback
given to `_transform` was being called more than once. There wasn't much information
to be found about this error either so I thought I'd include what I figured out here.

Answer (score 8):

`push` will return false if the stream you are writing to (in this case, a file output stream) has too much data buffered.  Since you're writing to disk, this makes sense: you are processing data faster than you can write it out.

When `out`'s buffer is full, your transform stream will fail to push, and start buffering data itself.  If that buffer should fill, then `inp`'s will start to fill.  This is how things should be working.  The piped streams are only going to process data as fast as the slowest link in the chain can handle it (once your buffers are full).

Comment: I suppose I'm confused as to what to do with the information when it returns `false`. To me, if a function has a return code (in this case `true` or `false`, it tells the caller some important piece of information. From what you've described above, it sounds like it's completely safe to ignore the return code. Is that what you're suggesting? If so, why? (poor documentation, etc)?

Comment: When you're using pipe, you can ignore the 'false'. I believe that `pipe` was designed to handle this internally. If you wanted to write your own custom backpressure mechanism, you could do so using the value returned from `push`

Answer (score 7):

I think `Transform` is suitable for this, but I would perform the inflate as a separate step in the pipeline.

Here's a quick and largely untested example:

```
var zlib        = require('zlib');
var stream      = require('stream');
var transformer = new stream.Transform();

// Properties used to keep internal state of transformer.
transformer._buffers    = [];
transformer._inputSize  = 0;
transformer._targetSize = 1024 * 38;

// Dump one 'output packet'
transformer._dump       = function(done) {
  // concatenate buffers and convert to binary string
  var buffer = Buffer.concat(this._buffers).toString('binary');

  // Take first 1024 packets.
  var packetBuffer = buffer.substring(0, this._targetSize);

  // Keep the rest and reset counter.
  this._buffers   = [ new Buffer(buffer.substring(this._targetSize)) ];
  this._inputSize = this._buffers[0].length;

  // output header
  this.push('HELLO WORLD');

  // output compressed packet buffer
  zlib.deflate(packetBuffer, function(err, compressed) {
    // TODO: handle `err`
    this.push(compressed);
    if (done) {
      done();
    }
  }.bind(this));
};

// Main transformer logic: buffer chunks and dump them once the
// target size has been met.
transformer._transform  = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  this._buffers.push(chunk);
  this._inputSize += chunk.length;

  if (this._inputSize >= this._targetSize) {
    this._dump(done);
  } else {
    done();
  }
};

// Flush any remaining buffers.
transformer._flush = function() {
  this._dump();
};

// Example:
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('depth_1000000')
  .pipe(zlib.createInflate())
  .pipe(transformer)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('depth_1000000.out'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer as it provides great insight into exactly what I'm trying to do. What I'm curious about is in your `_dump` function, how would you handle when `this.push(compressed)` returned `false`? This happens once in a while and I think it has to be a side effect of *back-pressure* on the stream. In these cases, how should one recover without losing data? Does that make sense?

Comment: @ScottSaad I'm not entirely sure to be honest. I also couldn't really find much about handling back pressure issues in transform streams :(

Comment: Wanted to let you know that I updated the question to be a bit more pinpointed as it refers to the back-pressure thing but wanted to thank you for the time you put into the above code. It's great! :)

Comment: can you explain what's going on here conceptually? seems just like code dump

Comment: @MrCholo the code reads _at least_ 1024*38 bytes from an inflated stream, and writes it back in chunks of _exactly_ 1024*38 bytes with an additional header in front of it (in the example, the string 'HELLO WORLD'). Each of these chunks (1024*38 + header.length bytes) is zlib-compressed.

Comment: ok sorry I don't understand, I still don't understand how it works - why exactly 1024*38, can you back up a bit

Comment: @MrCholo the 'exactly 1024*38' requirement is from the original question. In `_transform` you see that the code collects all the chunks of data (into `this._buffers`) until its size exceeds `this._targetSize` (which is set to 1024*38). In `_dump` the first 1024*38 bytes are extracted (using `buffer.substring()`), the header is passed on (using `this.push()`) and the extracted bytes are deflated using zlib (the result of which is also passed on). Be aware that the size of `this._buffers` may be larger than 1024*38 bytes, so there's some additional code to keep the excess for the 'next round'.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into a similar problem lately, needing to handle backpressure in an inflating transform stream - the secret to handling `push()` returning false is to register and handle the `'drain'` event on the stream

```
_transform(data, enc, callback) {
  const continueTransforming = () => {
    // ... do some work / parse the data, keep state of where we're at etc
    if(!this.push(event)) 
         this._readableState.pipes.once('drain', continueTransforming); // will get called again when the reader can consume more data
    if(allDone)
       callback();
  }
  continueTransforming()
}
```

NOTE this is a bit hacky as we're reaching into the internals and `pipes` can even be an array of `Readable`s but it does work in the common case of `....pipe(transform).pipe(...`

Would be great if someone from the Node community can suggest a "correct" method for handling `.push()` returning false

Comment: It's 2018 is this still kind of work-around still required today, or will pipe handle the backpressure internally from my transform?

If so could probably make a more generic solution as a module, to use a "BackPressure" transformer after the transform stream running into a backpressure issue, which could have options to process the chunks at a fixed sized buffer and queue limits.

Maybe someone already made such a module?

More information on backpressuring on streams.
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

Comment: TLDR: When using pipes node handles backpressure but with custom transformers you need to handle it internally. So yes we need to handle internally.

Comment: I think the better way is to continue processing as soon as `_read` is called, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43811543/12749249 , instead of looking at the internal `_readableState`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following Ledion's example and created a utility Transform class which assists with backpressure.  The utility adds an async method named addData, which the implementing Transform can await.

```
'use strict';

const { Transform } = require('stream');

/**
 * The BackPressureTransform class adds a utility method addData which
 * allows for pushing data to the Readable, while honoring back-pressure.
 */
class BackPressureTransform extends Transform {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }

  /**
   * Asynchronously add a chunk of data to the output, honoring back-pressure.
   *
   * @param {String} data
   * The chunk of data to add to the output.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   * A Promise resolving after the data has been added.
   */
  async addData(data) {
    // if .push() returns false, it means that the readable buffer is full
    // when this occurs, we must wait for the internal readable to emit
    // the 'drain' event, signalling the readable is ready for more data
    if (!this.push(data)) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const errorHandler = error => {
          this.emit('error', error);
          reject();
        };
        const boundErrorHandler = errorHandler.bind(this);

        this._readableState.pipes.on('error', boundErrorHandler);
        this._readableState.pipes.once('drain', () => {
          this._readableState.pipes.removeListener('error', boundErrorHandler);
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  BackPressureTransform
};
```

Using this utility class, my Transforms look like this now:

```
'use strict';

const { BackPressureTransform } = require('./back-pressure-transform');

/**
 * The Formatter class accepts the transformed row to be added to the output file.
 * The class provides generic support for formatting the result file.
 */
class Formatter extends BackPressureTransform {
  constructor() {
    super({
      encoding: 'utf8',
      readableObjectMode: false,
      writableObjectMode: true
    });

    this.anyObjectsWritten = false;
  }

  /**
   * Called when the data pipeline is complete.
   *
   * @param {Function} callback
   * The function which is called when final processing is complete.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   * A Promise resolving after the flush completes.
   */
  async _flush(callback) {
    // if any object is added, close the surrounding array
    if (this.anyObjectsWritten) {
      await this.addData('\n]');
    }

    callback(null);
  }

  /**
   * Given the transformed row from the ETL, format it to the desired layout.
   *
   * @param {Object} sourceRow
   * The transformed row from the ETL.
   *
   * @param {String} encoding
   * Ignored in object mode.
   *
   * @param {Function} callback
   * The callback function which is called when the formatting is complete.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   * A Promise resolving after the row is transformed.
   */
  async _transform(sourceRow, encoding, callback) {
    // before the first object is added, surround the data as an array
    // between each object, add a comma separator
    await this.addData(this.anyObjectsWritten ? ',\n' : '[\n');

    // update state
    this.anyObjectsWritten = true;

    // add the object to the output
    const parsed = JSON.stringify(sourceRow, null, 2).split('\n');
    for (const [index, row] of parsed.entries()) {
      // prepend the row with 2 additional spaces since we're inside a larger array
      await this.addData(`  ${row}`);

      // add line breaks except for the last row
      if (index < parsed.length - 1) {
        await this.addData('\n');
      }
    }

    callback(null);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Formatter
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a solution similar to [Ledion's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51508711/3344118) without needing to dive into the internals of the current stream pipeline. You can achieve this via:

```
_transform(data, enc, callback) {
  const continueTransforming = () => {
    // ... do some work / parse the data, keep state of where we're at etc
    if(!this.push(event)) 
         this.once('data', continueTransforming); // will get called again when the reader can consume more data
    if(allDone)
       callback();
  }
  continueTransforming()
}
```

This works because `data` is only emitted when someone downstream is consuming the `Transform`'s readable buffer that you're `this.push()`-ing to. So whenever the downstream has capacity to pull off of this buffer, you should be able to start writing back to the buffer.

The flaw with listening for `drain` on the downstream (other than reaching into the internals of node) is that you also are relying on your `Transform`'s buffer having been drained as well, which there's no guarantee that it has been when the downstream emits `drain`.

Comment: This is quite the clever solution. Thanks!

Comment: Where does `allDone` get defined/updated? Does it get set to true if `this.push` returns true?

Answer (score 0):

Mike Lippert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43811543/1137679) is the closest to the truth, I think. It appears that waiting for a new `_read()` call to begin again from the reading stream is the only way that the `Transform` is actively notified that the reader is ready. I wanted to share a simple example of how I override `_read()` temporarily.

```
_transform(buf, enc, callback) {

  // prepend any unused data from the prior chunk.
  if (this.prev) {
    buf = Buffer.concat([ this.prev, buf ]);
    this.prev = null;
  }

  // will keep transforming until buf runs low on data.
  if (buf.length < this.requiredData) {
    this.prev = buf;
    return callback();
  }

  var result = // do something with data...
  var nextbuf = buf.slice(this.requiredData);

  if (this.push(result)) {
    // Continue transforming this chunk
    this._transform(nextbuf, enc, callback);
  }
  else {
    // Node is warning us to slow down (applying "backpressure")
    // Temporarily override _read request to continue the transform
    this._read = function() {
        delete this._read;
        this._transform(nextbuf, enc, callback);
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the comment mentioned in the source code for transform and the reference link keeps being changed so I will leave this here for reference:

```
// a transform stream is a readable/writable stream where you do
// something with the data.  Sometimes it's called a "filter",
// but that's not a great name for it, since that implies a thing where
// some bits pass through, and others are simply ignored.  (That would
// be a valid example of a transform, of course.)
//
// While the output is causally related to the input, it's not a
// necessarily symmetric or synchronous transformation.  For example,
// a zlib stream might take multiple plain-text writes(), and then
// emit a single compressed chunk some time in the future.
//
// Here's how this works:
//
// The Transform stream has all the aspects of the readable and writable
// stream classes.  When you write(chunk), that calls _write(chunk,cb)
// internally, and returns false if there's a lot of pending writes
// buffered up.  When you call read(), that calls _read(n) until
// there's enough pending readable data buffered up.
//
// In a transform stream, the written data is placed in a buffer.  When
// _read(n) is called, it transforms the queued up data, calling the
// buffered _write cb's as it consumes chunks.  If consuming a single
// written chunk would result in multiple output chunks, then the first
// outputted bit calls the readcb, and subsequent chunks just go into
// the read buffer, and will cause it to emit 'readable' if necessary.
//
// This way, back-pressure is actually determined by the reading side,
// since _read has to be called to start processing a new chunk.  However,
// a pathological inflate type of transform can cause excessive buffering
// here.  For example, imagine a stream where every byte of input is
// interpreted as an integer from 0-255, and then results in that many
// bytes of output.  Writing the 4 bytes {ff,ff,ff,ff} would result in
// 1kb of data being output.  In this case, you could write a very small
// amount of input, and end up with a very large amount of output.  In
// such a pathological inflating mechanism, there'd be no way to tell
// the system to stop doing the transform.  A single 4MB write could
// cause the system to run out of memory.
//
// However, even in such a pathological case, only a single written chunk
// would be consumed, and then the rest would wait (un-transformed) until
// the results of the previous transformed chunk were consumed.
```