# How do I apply back-pressure to node streams?

Tags: node.js, stream

While attempting to experiment with Node.JS streams I ran into an interesting conundrum. When the input (Readable) stream pushes more data then the destination (Writable) cares about I was unable to apply back-pressure correctly.

The two methods I attempted was to return false from the `Writable.prototype._write` and to retain a reference to the Readable so I can call `Readable.pause()` from the Writable. Neither solution helped much which I'll explain.

In my exercise (which you can view [the full source as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/sukima/73932352b63eecc9cd3d)) I have three streams:

## Readable - PasscodeGenerator

```
util.inherits(PasscodeGenerator, stream.Readable);
function PasscodeGenerator(prefix) {
  stream.Readable.call(this, {objectMode: true});
  this.count  = 0;
  this.prefix = prefix || '';
}
PasscodeGenerator.prototype._read = function() {
  var passcode = '' + this.prefix + this.count;
  if (!this.push({passcode: passcode})) {
    this.pause();
    this.once('drain', this.resume.bind(this));
  }
  this.count++;
};
```

I thought that the return code from `this.push()` was enough to self pause and wait for the `drain` event to resume.

## Transform - Hasher

```
util.inherits(Hasher, stream.Transform);
function Hasher(hashType) {
  stream.Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});
  this.hashType = hashType;
}
Hasher.prototype._transform = function(sample, encoding, next) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash(this.hashType);
  hash.setEncoding('hex');
  hash.write(sample.passcode);
  hash.end();
  sample.hash = hash.read();
  this.push(sample);
  next();
};
```

Simply add the hash of the passcode to the object.

## Writable - SampleConsumer

```
util.inherits(SampleConsumer, stream.Writable);
function SampleConsumer(max) {
  stream.Writable.call(this, {objectMode: true});
  this.max   = (max != null) ? max : 10;
  this.count = 0;
}
SampleConsumer.prototype._write = function(sample, encoding, next) {
  this.count++;
  console.log('Hash %d (%s): %s', this.count, sample.passcode, sample.hash);
  if (this.count < this.max) {
    next();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Here I want to consume the data as fast as possible until I reach my max number of samples and then end the stream. I tried using `this.end()` instead of `return false` but that caused the dreaded **write called after end** problem. Returning false does stop everything if the sample size is small but when it is large I get an out of memory error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20869905/227176) in theory the Write stream would return false causing the streams to buffer until the buffers were full (16 by default for `objectMode`) and eventually the Readable would call it's `this.pause()` method. But `16 + 16 + 16 = 48`; that's 48 objects in buffer till things fill up and the system is clogged. Actually less because there is no cloning involved so the objects passed between them is the same reference. Would that not mean only 16 objects in memory till the high water mark halts everything?

Lastly I realize I could have the Writable reference the Readable to call it's pause method using closures. However, this solution means the Writable stream knows to much about another object. I'd have to pass in a reference:

```
var foo = new PasscodeGenerator('foobar');
foo
  .pipe(new Hasher('md5'))
  .pipe(new SampleConsumer(samples, foo));
```

And this feels out of norm for how streams would work. I thought back-pressure was enough to cause a Writable to stop a Readable from pushing data and prevent out of memory errors.

An analogous example would be the Unix `head` command. Implementing that in Node I would assume that the destination could **end** and not just ignore causing the source to keep pushing data even if the destination has enough data to satisfy the beginning portion of the file.

How do I idiomatically construct custom streams such that when the destination is ready to *end* the source stream doesn't attempt to push more data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7401) with how `_read()` is called internally. Since your `_read()` is always pushing synchronously/immediately, the internal stream implementation can get into a loop in the right conditions. `_read()` implementations are [generally](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1) [expected](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b513a3332163ad89cdb459f5877ee181b40f91c5/lib/_stream_readable.js#L249) to do some sort of async I/O (e.g. reading from disk or network).

The workaround for this (as noted in the link above) is to make your `_read()` asynchronous *at least* some of the time. You could also just make it async every time it's called with:

```
PasscodeGenerator.prototype._read = function(n) {
  var passcode = '' + this.prefix + this.count;
  var self = this;

  // `setImmediate()` delays the push until the beginning
  // of the next tick of the event loop
  setImmediate(function() {
    self.push({passcode: passcode});
  });

  this.count++;
};
```